# Ideal diode IV characteristics

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, diodes

[image: img]

If I know that the Ideal Diode only allows current to flow once V > 0, how would I go about implementing the two resistors into the IV graph? How do I analyse the circuit as a whole IV graph?

Comment: Usually the best way is to break the circuit down into two circuits, one in which voltage is =<0 the other when >0.

What does the ideal diode look like in terms of current under each of those conditions?

Comment: The current line is just a vertical line past v>0, I think if you add this knowledge to the IV characteristic graph of a resistor it would be 1/R graph where R = 12.5k past v>0?

Comment: If I is negative, current in D and R2 is zero. Is that enough of a hint?

Comment: Yes. Right half of curve is V = I * 12.5K. Now what about the left half of the curve, where I < 0?

Comment: it should just be a flat horizontal line where v = 0 correct?

Comment: Please don't remove images from the question that are necessary to understand what you're asking. I went ahead and put it back for you.

Comment: For V>0, R = 12.5k, as you said. But what is R when V<0?